# Why do `pydf` and `df` show different disk usage percentage?

Tags: disk-usage

I noticed several times that `pydf` and `df` give a bit different disk usage values.
For example:

```
$ df -h | grep sdb1
/dev/sdb1        11T  9.6T  705G  94% /mnt/disk
$ pydf | grep sdb1
/dev/sdb1   11T  10T  704G 88.6 [############.] /mnt/disk
```

`pydf` shows 10TB / 88.6%  used and `df -h` shows 9.6TB / 94% used.

Even if I add inodes, which `pydf -i` shows:

```
$ pydf -i | grep sdb1
/dev/sdb1   349M 205k  349M  0.1 [.............] /mnt/disk
```

It's clearly too small amount of disk space to make up for 0.4TB of space.

Note - the difference **is not in free disk space** - it's a "live" system, so free disk space changed a little (704GB vs 705GB) between the commands - when I run it on idle system and use KB, it's the same number from `pydf` as from `df`)

Can anyone explain the difference?

Examples are from debian linux 10, but I've seen it on other systems too.

### Additional information:

block size is 4096 bytes, and when forced to use block size, the comparison looks like this (edited to match "columns"):

```
$ (df --block-size=4096 && pydf --blocks) | grep sdb1
/dev/sdb1  2906334056 2568838216 191006112  94% /mnt/disk
/dev/sdb1  2906334056 2568838332 191005996  88.4 [#######.] /mnt/disk
```

again, since it's a "live system", the values are a bit different, but for this purpose I think it's ok to call those values (except percentage) the same.

As for what is on that filesystem - it's basicaly DVR (Digital Video Recorder) data disk - so there are large video clips, mostly 50-300MB, and almost no other (smaller) files.

Comment: out of interest : why do you compare pydf output to df -h one ? Shouldn't you compare df -h output to pydf -h ? Irrespective of this, you could probably post the output of cat /etc/pydfrc as well as cat ~/.pydfrc as part of your question

Comment: @MC68020 technically, you're correct, but because pydf does "-h" somewhat implicitly, I think (you can clearly see the units are the same) it's ok for this case. As for configs,  I didn't do anything to /etc/pydfrc, so it's "default values" (I can still post it if you confirm that it may be important), ~/.pydfrc does not exist.

Comment: What is the blocksize of the underlying filesystem ? What is the discrepancy when asking for number of blocks ? (df --block-size=the_actualsize vs pydf --blocks) ?

Comment: @MC68020 - I added this to the question

Comment: One thing indeed curious is that df appears totally wrong in its used-blocks/total blocks computation. Possibly adding the reserved-blocks percentage (defaults on 5%) when pydf would not.

Comment: @MC68020 - and yet I'm willing to trust df more, because `pydf` is "cool new df display hack", while `df` is "old and trusted" (at least how I see it), so maybe @thrig 's answer is the answer - df correctly prints how much space is used, including losses by "blocks fragmentation", while `pydf` just gives ratio of values without "blocks fragmentation"..

Comment: @MC68020 unfortunately, on some other system, the difference is less than 5% :(

Answer (score 1):

From a `df(1)` man page one might read something like

> Values are displayed in 512-byte per block counts

so one conclusion is that `df` measures by blocks and the other tool by
something else. Both these tools are probably using some form of `stat`
call (`lstat`, probably) to obtain information about the sizes of the
files; over in a `stat(2)` man page one might notice

```
struct stat {
    ...
    off_t           st_size;    /* file size, in bytes */
    blkcnt_t        st_blocks;  /* blocks allocated for file */
```

that there is a file size in bytes and a number of blocks allocated for
the file. This may suggest a test, what is the st_size and st_blocks for
a file containing one byte?

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        struct stat buf;
        stat("file", &buf);
        printf("size\t%lld\nblocks\t%lld\n", buf.st_size, buf.st_blocks);
        return 0;
}
```

This script compiled to `blocksize` and with a suitable test file:

```
$ make blocksize
cc -O2 -pipe    -o blocksize blocksize.c
$ printf 1 > file
$ ./blocksize
size    1
blocks  4
```

shows that our one byte file has a size of 1, but on this system
consumes 4 blocks of space. The block count and block size may vary, but
this will account for the difference between a tool that counts by file
size (`st_size`), and another that counts how many filesystem blocks (`st_blocks`) are used.